# Django retrieve data from another form

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and would like to know how can I save the teacher's email when the teacher logs in with LoginFormView shown below. After the teacher logs in, he can create a class using CreateClassForm.

I have problem trying to store ClassTeacherTeaches model into the database under CreateClassForm when the teacher creates a new class. How to I retrieve the teacher's email from LoginFormView and store the teacher's email and get the auto incremented class id (this is created once teacher creates a new class) into ClassTeacherTeaches model database?

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="", null=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.full_name

    def set_full_name(self, fname):
        self.full_name = fname

    def get_short_name(self):
        pass

    def get_full_name(self):
        pass

class Class(models.Model):
    classid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)


class ClassTeacherTeaches(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('classid', 'teacher_email'),)

    classid = models.ForeignKey(Class)
    teacher_email = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

form.py

```
 class CreateClassForm(forms.Form):
        class_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Module Code'}), label='')

        class Meta:
            model = Class
            fields = ['class_name']

        def save(self, commit=True):
            data = self.cleaned_data
            module = Class(class_name=data['class_name'])

            if commit:
                module.save()
            return module

  class LoginFormView(FormView):
            form_class = LoginForm
            template_name = 'App/index.html'
            success_url = '/'

            def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                login_form = self.form_class(request.POST)
                register_form = RegistrationForm()
                if login_form.is_valid():
                    auth = EmailAuthBackend()
                    user = auth.authenticate(email=request.POST['email'], password=request.POST['password'])
                    if user is not None:

                        django_login(request, user)
                        return HttpResponseRedirect("../instructormodule")

                else:
                    return self.render_to_response(
                        self.get_context_data(
                            login_form=login_form,
                            register_form=register_form
                        )
                    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't "retrieve the teacher's email from the login form". The teacher is *logged in*; therefore you retrieve the email from the logged-in uesr.

```
class CreateClassForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    def save(self, commit=True):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        module = Class(class_name=data['class_name'])
        module.teacher_email = self.request.user

        if commit:
            module.save()
        return module
```

Note, it makes no sense to call that field `teacher_email`; it points at the entire User model, so it should be called just `teacher`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Daniel's answer, but would like to give better direction here. Which is having your Class model linked to your users, by ForeignKey. This way you can related your classes to Users and hence you will have pointer to the user who created the class.

Please read django documentation on this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/